# missing ; before statement on my first line `pm.view`

Tags: javascript

```
var pm.view= {
    tests_enabled: true 
};

(function () {
    pm.view.methodName1= function () {

    };

    pm.view.methodName2 = function () {

    };

})();
```

Why do i get an error missing ; before statement on my first line `pm.view`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable declarations in JavaScript must be one word only, so the `pm` object should use `var` for declaration and then the `view` can be attached to it. If `pm` and `view` are being declared at the same time:

```
var pm = {
  view: {
    tests_enabled: true 
  }
};
```

or if `pm` is already defined, just use dot notation to add `view` to it:

```
pm.view = {
  tests_enabled: true 
};
```

Comment: If `pm` is defined before, it is fine. He just needs no `var`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare a object property directly.
First define your pm object and the add the tests_enable property to it.

```
var pm = {};
pm.view = {
   tests_enabled: true
};
```

or you can use the below synatx:

```
var pm = {
   view : {
      tests_enabled: true
   }
};
```

Hope, this will solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

`var` is only needed when you are declaring a variable (in the current scope). `pm.view` is not a (single) variable, `view` is a property of the `pm` object. First, you should declare `pm` as an object, and then you can add properties to it without the `var` keyword:

```
var pm = {};
pm.view= {
    tests_enabled: true 
};
console.log(pm.view.tests_enabled);
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PB7cu/)

​

Answer (score 0):

Try just deleting 'var'.
Sorry, I can't post a comment.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: pm is not defined`

Comment: You have defined pm? If not, it's an obvious error. You need to add `pm = {};` before.

Comment: OP said the first line of the code is the `var` line. So he has no `pm` object defined. An obvious error, in fact, but not for him. That is why he asked.